# Material-UI Dropdown overflowed in Dialog

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use a dropdown select inside of a `Dialog` (modal). However, the options get cut off by the bottom of the modal.
How can I get the options to continue further down past the bottom border?

I'm using MUI v5.

```
<Dialog open={open}>
  <DialogContent>
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={options}
      // getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Numbers" />}
    />
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

(extreme) example: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-breeze-mgsno?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove or set the `disablePortal` prop to `false` in your `Autocomplete`. If you use [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in the dropdown list. The dropdown's real DOM element will be attached outside of the Dialog hierarchy (you can use inspect element to confirm it), so its size isn't constrained by the layout of the dialog.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]